# How to get week of year figure in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, time

Is there a simple way how to get week of year information from a `Date` object or from millis time in `GWT` on the client side?

Comment: Find a way using JavaScript [GitHub - getWeek.js](https://gist.github.com/dblock/1081513l) and call from GWT JSNI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Date date = new Date();
Date yearStart = new Date(date.getYear(), 0, 0);

int week = (int) (date.getTime() - yearStart.getTime())/(7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Note that this will give you a week in a Date object, which has no time zone information. When you use it, you may have to adjust it using the time zone information.

Comment: If I know the offset from `date.getTimezoneOffset()` how to I include it into the calculation?

Comment: date.getTime() - yearStart.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000, because TimezoneOffset is measured in minutes.

Comment: Even though not 100% precise (as I believe there are different definitions what counts as a first week in year for different locales) I will use this solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using the modern API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        int weekOfYear = date.get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        System.out.println(weekOfYear);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
18
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

How to do it with GWT object not sure but because GWT code is converted to javascript at compile time, so you could make something like this:

http://javascript.about.com/library/blweekyear.htm